# How can I add "sub" dataframes or subrows in Pandas Python with different operation per row and per object?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this DataFrame:

```
>>> data = [['Ob01',1,2,3],['Ob02',4,5,6],['Ob03',7,8,9]]
>>> dfr = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'A','B','C'])
```

dfr

```
   Name  A  B  C
0  Ob01  1  2  3
1  Ob02  4  5  6
2  Ob03  7  8  9
```

My problem is that I need to do some operation for each Object in the column "Name", and to add new sub rows per each object.
I have to do some operation for each Object, for example multiplying by 2 the "A", "B", "C" properties and also divide by 3 the past result, but I need to see those operations results in other rows, like this:

```
   Name  Op    A    B    C
0  Ob01  Val   1    2    3
         mul2  2    4    6 
         div3 0.66 1.33  2 
1  Ob02  Val   4    5    6
         mul2  8    10  12 
         div3 2.66 3.33  4 
2  Ob03  Val   7    8    9
         mul2  14  16   18 
         div3 4.66 5.33  6
```

Or it will be better if I add Columns per operation per object?
Anyway i don't know where to start, My list of objects is way to long, but i wanted to represent some of my data for exemplify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas-dataframe-melt) + [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas-dataframe-pivot) +  [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html#pandas-dataframe-stack) option:

```
new_df = dfr.reset_index().melt(id_vars=['index', 'Name'], value_name='Val')
new_df['mul2'] = new_df['Val'] * 2
new_df['div3'] = new_df['Val'] / 3
new_df = (
    new_df.pivot(index=['index', 'Name'], columns='variable')
        .stack(level=0)
        .reset_index()
        .set_index('index')
        .rename(columns={'level_2': 'Op'})
        .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
)
```

---

A [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html#pandas-dataframe-set-index)  + [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas-concat) +  [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html#pandas-dataframe-stack):

`concat` axis=1 with `keys` set to assign values to each frame.

Then and clean up indexes and columns etc:

```
dfr = dfr.reset_index().set_index(['index', 'Name'])
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C']
mul2 = dfr[cols] * 2
div3 = dfr[cols] / 3

new_df = (
    pd.concat(
        (dfr, mul2, div3),
        axis=1,
        keys=('Val', 'mul2', 'div3')
    )
        .stack(level=0)
        .reset_index()
        .set_index('index')
        .rename(columns={'level_2': 'Op'})
        .rename_axis(None)
)
```

`new_df`:

```
   Name    Op          A          B     C
0  Ob01   Val   1.000000   2.000000   3.0
0  Ob01  div3   0.333333   0.666667   1.0
0  Ob01  mul2   2.000000   4.000000   6.0
1  Ob02   Val   4.000000   5.000000   6.0
1  Ob02  div3   1.333333   1.666667   2.0
1  Ob02  mul2   8.000000  10.000000  12.0
2  Ob03   Val   7.000000   8.000000   9.0
2  Ob03  div3   2.333333   2.666667   3.0
2  Ob03  mul2  14.000000  16.000000  18.0
```

Answer (score 0):

use `set_index` and `pd.concat`:

```
df = df.set_index('Name')
df = pd.concat([df.assign(OP = 'Val') , df.mul(2).assign(OP = 'mul2') , df.div(3).assign(OP = 'div3')]).sort_values('Name')
```

To further transform:

```
df = df.groupby([df.index,'OP']).agg(float)
df = df.convert_dtypes()
```

OUTPUT:

```
                  A         B   C
Name OP                          
Ob01 Val        1.0       2.0   3
     div3  0.333333  0.666667   1
     mul2       2.0       4.0   6
Ob02 Val        4.0       5.0   6
     div3  1.333333  1.666667   2
     mul2       8.0      10.0  12
Ob03 Val        7.0       8.0   9
     div3  2.333333  2.666667   3
     mul2      14.0      16.0  18
```

Comment: Nice one, I was doing something similar ... maybe should add `df.groupby(['Name','OP']).agg(int)` at the end ...

Comment: @DanailPetrov Thanks for the suggestion :)