# Pandas how to have row with specified value and then subrow of this row

Tags: python, django, pandas, dataframe

Hello everyone so im creating an xlsx file using Pandas , im using json_normalize() to proceed data now i know their is MultiIndex Dataframe , but their is not a way how to affect a value to the main row like the image bellow , is their is a way to proceed that ?

```
data = [
{"header": "INDUSTRY",
"surface": 540,
"gaz": 405,
"fioul": 135}, 
{
"header": "AGRI",
"surface": 540,
"gaz": 405,
"fioul": 135
},
{
"header": "INDUSTRY",
"surface": 55,
"gaz": 405,
"fioul": 135
},
]
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add "sub" dataframes or subrows in Pandas Python with different operation per row and per object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67712273/how-can-i-add-sub-dataframes-or-subrows-in-pandas-python-with-different-operat)

Comment: @IñigoMoreno no i have seen this one and just modify it to make it work

Answer (score 0):

i just used empty index and it worked

```
import pandas as pd

df_multindex = pd.DataFrame({'valeurs': [5,0, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6],
'unités': ["m",360, 180, 360, 360, 540,720]},
index=[['surface','surface', 'surface', 
'surface', 'montant', 'montant', 'montant'],
['','gaz', 'charbon', 'fioul',
"", 'montant charbon', 'montant fioul']])

df_multindex.index.rename(['champ',''], inplace=True)

df_multindex
```

[image]